# Tikz Matrix No shape named

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I try to write my bachelor thesis with LaTeX. In this I have problems with TikZ. I like to make braces over my matrices like this:

[image]

I have several problems:

- can´t draw dashed line between 6. and 7.row
- the nodes (I hope that u_1 etc. are nodes?) are not at the right position
- and after six nodes i can't add anymore. It says "No shape named 1-7"
- I like to have overbrace over every 3 columns (so from 1 to 3, 3-6 and 6-9) with a letter on it

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me :)

And this is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing, calc, positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax ]
\matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]},,nodes in empty cells]
{
    d^{(1)}_1\\
    d^{(1)}_2\\
    d^{(1)}_3\\
    d^{(1)}_4\\
    d^{(1)}_5\\
    d^{(1)}_6\\
    %
    d^{(2)}_1\\
    d^{(2)}_2\\
    d^{(2)}_3\\
    d^{(2)}_4\\
    d^{(2)}_5\\
    d^{(2)}_6\\
 };

\draw[dashed] ($0.5*(m-6-1.south west)+0.5*(m-7-1.north west)$) --
($0.5*(m-6-1.south east)+0.5*(m-7-1.north east)$);

\node[left=12pt of m-2-1] (left-1) {i};
\node[left=12pt of m-5-1] (left-2) {k};
\node[left=12pt of m-8-1] (left-3) {i};
\node[left=12pt of m-11-1](left-4) {k};

\node[rectangle,left delimiter=\{] (del-left-1) at ($0.5*(left-1.east) +0.5*(left-2.east)$) {\tikz{\path (left-1.north east) rectangle (left-2.south west);}};
\node[left=12pt] at (del-left-1.west) {$E_1$};

\node[rectangle,left delimiter=\{] (del-left-3) at ($0.5*(left-3.east) +0.5*(left-4.east)$) {\tikz{\path (left-3.north east) rectangle (left-4.south west);}};
\node[left=12pt] at (del-left-3.west) {$E_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
=
\begin{tikzpicture}
[baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax ]
\matrix (n)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]},column sep=0.5cm,nodes in empty cells]{
1       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
        &1      &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
        &       &1      &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
        &       &       &1      &       &       &       &       &       \\
        &       &       &       &1      &       &       &       &       \\
        &       &       &       &       &1      &       &       &       \\
        &       &       &1      &       &       &       &       &       \\
        &       &       &       &1      &       &       &       &       \\
        &       &       &       &       &1      &       &       &       \\
        &       &       &       &       &       &1      &       &       \\
        &       &       &       &       &       &       &1      &       \\
        &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &1      \\
};

\draw[dashed] ($0.5*(m-6-1.south west)+0.5*(m-7-1.north west)$) --($0.5*(m-6-9.south east)+0.5*(m-7-9.north east)$);

\node[above=of n-1-1] (top-1) {$u_1$};
\node[above=of n-1-2] (top-2) {$w_1$};
\node[above=of n-1-3] (top-3) {$\phi_1$};
\node[above=12pt of n-1-4] (top-4) {$u_2$};
\node[above=12pt of n-1-5] (top-5) {$w_2$};
\node[above=12pt of n-1-6] (top-6) {$\phi_2$};
\node[above=10pt of m-1-7] (top-7) {$u_3$};
\node[above=10pt of m-1-8] (top-8) {$w_3$};
\node[above=10pt of m-1-9] (top-9) {$\phi_3$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{eqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should avoid `eqnarray`. There are some spacing issues around the alignment point. Then, instead of `Tikz` I would use an equation environment, here `displaymath` and use `array` to draw the matrices. To get the braces right there are some font dependent distances that you might want to change. It is probably not the nicest solution but I think it works. And since it is your thesis you have full control of the type setting and it should probably not be compiled with some other fonts or sizes. I also assumed the lower E_1 should be E_2 (maybe completely wrong), and that the letters should be above the matrix. And I added some dashed vertical lines also since it looked good:-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}%%% dashed lines
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing, calc, positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \begin{array}{c}
    E_1\left\{\rule{0pt}{57pt}\right.\\[10pt]
    E_2\left\{\rule{0pt}{57pt}\right.
  \end{array}%
  \left[
    \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      d^{(1)}_1\\[5pt]
      \llap{\ensuremath i\rule{8pt}{0pt}}d^{(1)}_2\\[5pt] %% Write the letters to the left of the vector
      d^{(1)}_3\\[5pt]
      d^{(1)}_4\\[5pt]
      \llap{\ensuremath k\rule{8pt}{0pt}}d^{(1)}_5\\[5pt]
      d^{(1)}_6\\[3pt]\hdashline[4pt/2pt]\\[-7pt] %% relatively centered line
      d^{(2)}_1\\[5pt]
      \llap{\ensuremath i\rule{8pt}{0pt}}d^{(2)}_2\\[5pt]
      d^{(2)}_3\\[5pt]
      d^{(2)}_4\\[5pt]
      \llap{\ensuremath k\rule{8pt}{0pt}}d^{(2)}_5\\[5pt]
      d^{(2)}_6
    \end{array}
  \right]
  =
  \begin{matrix}
    \overbrace{\rule{58pt}{0pt}}^{A}
    \overbrace{\rule{58pt}{0pt}}^{B}
    \overbrace{\rule{58pt}{0pt}}^{C}\\
    \strut\\
    \left[
      \begin{array}{@{}ccc;{4pt/2pt}ccc;{4pt/2pt}ccc@{}}
        \raisebox{15pt}[0pt][0pt]{$u_1$} &
        \raisebox{15pt}[0pt][0pt]{$w_1$} &
        \raisebox{15pt}[0pt][0pt]{$\phi_1$} &
        \raisebox{15pt}[0pt][0pt]{$u_2$} &
        \raisebox{15pt}[0pt][0pt]{$w_2$} &
        \raisebox{15pt}[0pt][0pt]{$\phi_2$} &
        \raisebox{15pt}[0pt][0pt]{$u_3$} &
        \raisebox{15pt}[0pt][0pt]{$w_3$} &
        \raisebox{15pt}[0pt][0pt]{$\phi_3$}\\[-10pt]
        1       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
                &1      &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
                &       &1      &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
                &       &       &1      &       &       &       &       &       \\
                &       &       &       &1      &       &       &       &       \\
                &       &       &       &       &1      &       &       &       \\\hdashline[4pt/2pt]
                &       &       &1      &       &       &       &       &       \\
                &       &       &       &1      &       &       &       &       \\
                &       &       &       &       &1      &       &       &       \\
                &       &       &       &       &       &1      &       &       \\
                &       &       &       &       &       &       &1      &       \\
                &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &1   
      \end{array}
    \right]\\
    \rule{0pt}{26pt}%% Extra space below to compensate for braces above
  \end{matrix}
\end{displaymath}
```

[image]

Edit for addressing the follow up question by the OP.

To swap the equality, i.e. to have the d-vector to the right, we must swap the braces also. That is, with some clipping of preamble and the large binary (?) matrix,

```
[...clip...]
                &       &       &       &       &       &       &1      &       \\
                &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &1   
      \end{array}
    \right]\\
    \rule{0pt}{26pt}
  \end{matrix}
  =
  \left[
    \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      d^{(1)}_1\\[5pt]
      d^{(1)}_2\rlap{\rule{8pt}{0pt}$i$}\\[5pt]
      d^{(1)}_3\\[5pt]
      d^{(1)}_4\\[5pt]
      d^{(1)}_5\rlap{\rule{8pt}{0pt}$k$}\\[5pt]
      d^{(1)}_6\\[3pt]\hdashline[4pt/2pt]\\[-7pt]
      d^{(2)}_1\\[5pt]
      d^{(2)}_2\rlap{\rule{8pt}{0pt}$i$}\\[5pt]
      d^{(2)}_3\\[5pt]
      d^{(2)}_4\\[5pt]
      d^{(2)}_5\rlap{\rule{8pt}{0pt}$k$}\\[5pt]
      d^{(2)}_6
    \end{array}
  \right]
  \begin{array}{c}
    \left.\rule{0pt}{57pt}\right\}E_1\\
    \left.\rule{0pt}{57pt}\right\}E_2
  \end{array}
\end{displaymath}
```

[image]

Comment: The result is nice, and it works, but there is a lot of visual formatting here... it's a bit against the Zen of LaTeX. +1 anyway...

Comment: Thank you for answering so fast :) it works and it looks really nice. Yeah and it should be E_2 :D. I will take this one, but is there a way to do it with Tikz too?

Comment: I have one last question @StefanH then i'm finished with my bachelor thesis. How can i get the left matrix (the one with E_1 and E_2) on the right side with the braces on the right side? Like this [...]=[d_1..] }E_1 ? I just managed it to look like this [...]=[d_1..] {. I would like to post the code but i guess it does not fit into the comments.

Comment: @user109900 See edit. The `\left` `\right` pair sets parenthesis around whatever is between. So `\left(\sum_i\right)` puts `()` around the sum. If you don't want anything put a dot, e.g. `\left.`. Here it encapsulates a `\rule` with zero length and height `57pt`. A `\rule{x}{y}` is just a black box with dimension `x` and `y`. Since the `x` dimension is zero it is not visible. You can see it by replacing `0pt` with `1pt`. I moved the i and k also, but they are part of the d-vector.

Answer (score 3):

This shows a solution using OP's `TiKZ` code:

Original code contains a typo which avoids drawing second dashed line. Node `m-6-1` is referenced while it should be `n-6-1`. So I've replaced

```
\draw[dashed] ($0.5*(m-6-1.south west)+0.5*(m-7-1.north west)$) --($0.5*(m-6-9.south east)+0.5*(m-7-9.north east)$);
```

with

```
\draw[dashed] (n.center-|n-1-1.west) --(n.center-|n-6-9.east);
```

A `TikZ` matrix is formed by inner nodes (`n-1-1`, `n-2-1`, ...) and the matrix node `n` which can also be drawn, referenced, ... As dashed line should go through `n.center` and between nodes `n-1-1` and `n-1-9`, a perpendicular coordinates system could be applied.

Next problem, alignment of upper nodes. This misplacement is due to different size of inner nodes. `above = of n-1-1` fixes the reference point in `n-1-1.north` and this point is not on the same horizontal line than `n-1-2.north` because `n-1-2` is an empty node. This problem can also be solved again with a perpendicular reference. Once node `top-1` is placed, one can use it as horizontal reference:

```
\node[above=3mm of n-1-1] (top-1) {$u_1$};
\node (top-2) at (top-1-|n-1-2) {$w_1$};
...
```

Finally horizontal overbraces can be drawn with a `decoration`:

```
\draw [decorate, decoration={brace, raise=0mm, amplitude=3mm}] (top-1.north west)--(top-3.north east) node[above=4mm, midway]{$A$};
```

[image]

The complete code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,decorations.pathreplacing, calc, positioning}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
[baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax ]
\matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]},,nodes in empty cells]
{
    d^{(1)}_1\\
    d^{(1)}_2\\
    d^{(1)}_3\\
    d^{(1)}_4\\
    d^{(1)}_5\\
    d^{(1)}_6\\
    %
    d^{(2)}_1\\
    d^{(2)}_2\\
    d^{(2)}_3\\
    d^{(2)}_4\\
    d^{(2)}_5\\
    d^{(2)}_6\\
 };

\draw[dashed] ($0.5*(m-6-1.south west)+0.5*(m-7-1.north west)$) --
($0.5*(m-6-1.south east)+0.5*(m-7-1.north east)$);

\node[left=12pt of m-2-1] (left-1) {i};
\node[left=12pt of m-5-1] (left-2) {k};
\node[left=12pt of m-8-1] (left-3) {i};
\node[left=12pt of m-11-1](left-4) {k};

\node[rectangle,left delimiter=\{] (del-left-1) at ($0.5*(left-1.east) +0.5*(left-2.east)$) {\tikz{\path (left-1.north east) rectangle (left-2.south west);}};
\node[left=12pt] at (del-left-1.west) {$E_1$};

\node[rectangle,left delimiter=\{] (del-left-3) at ($0.5*(left-3.east) +0.5*(left-4.east)$) {\tikz{\path (left-3.north east) rectangle (left-4.south west);}};
\node[left=12pt] at (del-left-3.west) {$E_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
=
\begin{tikzpicture}
[baseline=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax ]
\matrix (n)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={[},right delimiter={]},column sep=0.5cm, nodes in empty cells]{
1       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
        &1      &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
        &       &1      &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
        &       &       &1      &       &       &       &       &       \\
        &       &       &       &1      &       &       &       &       \\
        &       &       &       &       &1      &       &       &       \\
        &       &       &1      &       &       &       &       &       \\
        &       &       &       &1      &       &       &       &       \\
        &       &       &       &       &1      &       &       &       \\
        &       &       &       &       &       &1      &       &       \\
        &       &       &       &       &       &       &1      &       \\
        &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &1      \\
};

\draw[dashed] (n.center-|n-1-1.west) --(n.center-|n-6-9.east);

\node[above=3mm of n-1-1] (top-1) {$u_1$};
\node (top-2) at (top-1-|n-1-2) {$w_1$};
\node (top-3) at (top-1-|n-1-3) {$\phi_1$};
\node (top-4) at (top-1-|n-1-4) {$u_2$};
\node (top-5) at (top-1-|n-1-5) {$w_2$};
\node (top-6) at (top-1-|n-1-6) {$\phi_2$};
\node (top-7) at (top-1-|n-1-7) {$u_3$};
\node (top-8) at (top-1-|n-1-8) {$w_3$};
\node (top-9) at (top-1-|n-1-9) {$\phi_4$};

\draw [decorate, decoration={brace, raise=0mm, amplitude=3mm}] (top-1.north west)--(top-3.north east) node[above=4mm, midway]{$A$};
\draw [decorate, decoration={brace, raise=0mm, amplitude=3mm}] (top-4.north west)--(top-6.north east) node[above=4mm, midway]{$B$};
\draw [decorate, decoration={brace, raise=0mm, amplitude=3mm}] (top-7.north west)--(top-9.north east) node[above=4mm, midway]{$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```